# 90% confidence interval around the median in using DescTools::medianCI()

Tags: r, confidence-interval

I need to get a 90% confidence interval around the median.

```
x <- c(251, 108, 27, 18, 195, 82, 222, 38, 81, 181, 140, 21, 43, 47, 15, 37, 46, 107, 19, 178, 95, 130, 60, 34, 48, 219, 338, 78, 117, 62, 40, 52)
MedianCI(x, conf.level=0.9)
```

the result is

```
median lwr.ci upr.ci 
 70     46    108  
attr(,"conf.level") [1] 0.9498975
```

It generates an interval for 0.949 level, but I want 0.9. What would be the right way to do it? The correct answer should be (70, 47, 108).

Comment: what package is this from? medians, and even more so CIs of medians, are going to be very sensitive in small data sets to the exact definition of a quantile (of which there are many ...)

Comment: @akrun Good idea. I tried that but in that case, I get 89% confidence which is less than 90%.

Comment: Can I ask how you know the correct answer? @akrun, `method="boot"` gives {34,  93}.

Comment: for example, `sapply(1:9,function(i) quantile(x,0.5,type=i))` gives either 62 or 70 depending on the method used ...

Comment: @BenBolker I am using `DescTools` package. I understand that it's going to be sensitive. I would be using it for a large dataset. Just trying this out for small datasets for now. This is a problem along with the manual solution from the book `Quantifying the User Experience by Jeff Sauro`

Comment: FWIW I can't even replicate: with your original data set I get 70 {47, 107}, and a realized confidence level of 0.889.  Can you `dput()` your data?

Comment: @BenBolker Sorry about that. I entered the wrong confidence level. Instead of 0.88 it should be 0.9. Updated the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two main issues here.

1. The method given in the book is approximate. As the author states, it's probably fine for most large-sample data sets, but it's actually farther from "correct" than the methods implemented by `MedianCI`
2. Especially for small data sets, it's unlikely that a confidence interval (however computed) will line up exactly with an observation in the data set: that's why the author says

> The results of the equation are **rounded up to the next integer** and the boundary of the confidence interval is between the two values in the data set.

(It's not clear to me why the results are rounded up for both the lower and the upper CI limit; I would have expected them to be rounded up for the upper limit and down for the lower limit ...)

By giving you the 0.949 confidence interval instead of the 0.9 you asked for, `MedianCI`is being conservative (the typical definition of the CI being an interval that includes the true value *at least* x% of the time); confidence level 0.89-0.94 will give you the 0.949 level, while values from 0.79-0.88 will give you the 0.889 level.

If you have follow-up questions about the technical details of my answer, you should probably ask on [CrossValidated](https://stats.stackexchange.com).  I don't know if there's a handy-dandy built-in function in an R package somewhere that implements the approximate method given in the book (although it should take only advanced-beginner R skill to implement; if you want to try it, give it a shot and feel free to ask another question when you get stuck ...)